# Entity Framework code-first migration ignoring [Key] and forcing composite key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create an object with a Guid primary key using `[Key]`, but Entity Framework keeps forcing the creation of a composite key.

```
public class Challenge
{
    [Key] 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ChallengerId { get; set; }
    public Guid ChallengeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChallengerId")]
    public virtual Player Challenger { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChallengeeId")]
    public virtual Player Challengee { get; set; }

    public DateTime Initiated { get; set; }
}
```

and its migration...

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Challenges",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ChallengerId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    ChallengeeId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    Initiated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Challenges", x => new { x.ChallengerId, x.ChallengeeId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Challenges_Players_ChallengeeId",
                        column: x => x.ChallengeeId,
                        principalTable: "Players",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Challenges_Players_ChallengerId",
                        column: x => x.ChallengerId,
                        principalTable: "Players",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });
```

Note that I've created the Player class using the same methodology, and Entity Framework respects the `[Key]` attribute there.

```
public class Player
{
    [Key] 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Challenger")]
    public virtual ICollection<Challenge> OutgoingChallenges { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Challengee")]
    public virtual ICollection<Challenge> IncomingChallenges { get; set; }
}
```

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Players",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Players", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Players_IdentityUser_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "IdentityUser",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

Even when I go into the migration and change

```
table.PrimaryKey("PK_Challenges", x => new { x.ChallengerId, x.ChallengeeId });
```

to

```
table.PrimaryKey("PK_Challenges", x => x.Id);
```

Entity Framework seems to be struggling, as it creates `Challenges` in the SQL database with a composite key.

I'm using .NET 6.

Comment: Do you have any fluent apis?

Comment: I'm not sure? It's a pretty new/sparse project. Why would that affect the entity builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the guilty culprit: AppDbContext.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Challenge>()
                    .HasForeignKey(c => new { c.ChallengerId, c.ChallengeeId });
```

Answer (score 0):

Might you be missing [Key] attribute in your Player model?

```
public class Player
{
    //Here should be a [Key] annotation
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Challenger")]
    public virtual ICollection<Challenge> OutgoingChallenges { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Challengee")]
    public virtual ICollection<Challenge> IncomingChallenges { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It would appear that I am, though my player model is behaving as intended. That might be preventing the foreign keys from mapping correctly.  Let me take a look and get back to you. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: That's not it. I'll update the question - Player's Id has a `[Key]`. Also, IIRC, it shouldn't need it - the Id convention should default to that being the primary key, right?

Comment: Well, I think you are right. However with auto migration, both versions create the tables and constraints successfully on my end.